# How to compare objects in array where one array contains calculated properties

Tags: arrays, powershell

fairly new to powershell so just looking for some guidance.

I'm trying to get a list of IP addresses from a DNS server and compare it with a list known list of addresses to check if any are missing.

A summary of my script so far:
-create/initialize some new array lists
-Build $expectedArray with a list of IP addresses
-query the domain controller for IP addresses in a given subnet, selecting the IP address as a calculated property and store the result in $result
-Use the Compare-Object cmdlet to compare what is in the $expectedArray with what's in the result of my query

As you can see below the output shows that the IP Address in the $result array has some characters surrounding it, so the comparison shows that they don't exist in the $expectedArray.

The thing that has me stumped is when I print out the $result array on it's own (without running it through Compare-Object), I get a nice list of IP addresses.

Can anyone shed some light as to what's going on and how I might go about fixing it? I have a feeling I will need to manipulate the string that gets stored in $result, bit I'm unsure of how to go about doing that.
I'm also open to other (better) ways of going about this.

Thanks in Advance.

Chris

**Code:**

```
    $expectedArray  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $Subnet = 1..255
    
    
    foreach($i in $Subnet){
        $expectedArray += "10.3.0.$i"
    }
    
     
    
    $result = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "mydomain.com" -ComputerName MyDomainController | 
    Where-Object { $_.RecordData.ipv4address -like '10.3.*'} | 
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = "IP Address"; Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}}
    
    
    $result
    $expectedArray
    
    
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $expectedArray -DifferenceObject $result -IncludeEqual
```

**Output**

```
InputObject              SideIndicator
-----------              -------------
@{IP Address=10.3.0.29}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.70}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.28}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.61}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.64}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.223} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.106} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.126} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.149} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.10.2}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.115} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.154} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.153} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.166} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.165} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.57}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.45}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.62}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.55}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.56}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.70}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.28}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.29}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.70}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.28}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.29}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.50}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.157} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.146} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.130} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.163} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.121} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.169} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.171} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.164} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.120} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.106} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.4}   =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.63}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.30}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.31}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.41}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.58}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.59}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.5}   =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.28}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.29}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.70}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.71}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.72}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.73}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.74}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.11}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.12}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.13}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.14}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.1}   =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.51}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.81}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.68}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.67}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.69}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.76}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.53}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.80}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.21}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.52}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.54}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.43}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.47}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.46}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.48}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.6}   =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.42}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.77}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.83}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.82}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.65}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.75}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.49}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.66}  =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.199} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.117} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.158} =>
@{IP Address=10.3.0.108} =>
10.3.0.1                 <=
10.3.0.2                 <=
10.3.0.3                 <=
10.3.0.4                 <=
10.3.0.5                 <=
10.3.0.6                 <=
10.3.0.7                 <=
10.3.0.8                 <=
10.3.0.9                 <=
10.3.0.10                <=
10.3.0.11                <=
10.3.0.12                <=
10.3.0.13                <=
10.3.0.14                <=
10.3.0.15                <=
10.3.0.16                <=
10.3.0.17                <=
10.3.0.18                <=
10.3.0.19                <=
10.3.0.20                <=
10.3.0.21                <=
10.3.0.22                <=
10.3.0.23                <=
10.3.0.24                <=
10.3.0.25                <=
10.3.0.26                <=
10.3.0.27                <=
10.3.0.28                <=
10.3.0.29                <=
10.3.0.30                <=
10.3.0.31                <=
10.3.0.32                <=
10.3.0.33                <=
10.3.0.34                <=
10.3.0.35                <=
10.3.0.36                <=
10.3.0.37                <=
10.3.0.38                <=
10.3.0.39                <=
10.3.0.40                <=
10.3.0.41                <=
10.3.0.42                <=
10.3.0.43                <=
10.3.0.44                <=
10.3.0.45                <=
10.3.0.46                <=
10.3.0.47                <=
10.3.0.48                <=
10.3.0.49                <=
10.3.0.50                <=
10.3.0.51                <=
10.3.0.52                <=
10.3.0.53                <=
10.3.0.54                <=
10.3.0.55                <=
10.3.0.56                <=
10.3.0.57                <=
10.3.0.58                <=
10.3.0.59                <=
10.3.0.60                <=
10.3.0.61                <=
10.3.0.62                <=
10.3.0.63                <=
10.3.0.64                <=
10.3.0.65                <=
10.3.0.66                <=
10.3.0.67                <=
10.3.0.68                <=
10.3.0.69                <=
10.3.0.70                <=
10.3.0.71                <=
10.3.0.72                <=
10.3.0.73                <=
10.3.0.74                <=
10.3.0.75                <=
10.3.0.76                <=
10.3.0.77                <=
10.3.0.78                <=
10.3.0.79                <=
10.3.0.80                <=
10.3.0.81                <=
10.3.0.82                <=
10.3.0.83                <=
10.3.0.84                <=
10.3.0.85                <=
10.3.0.86                <=
10.3.0.87                <=
10.3.0.88                <=
10.3.0.89                <=
10.3.0.90                <=
10.3.0.91                <=
10.3.0.92                <=
10.3.0.93                <=
10.3.0.94                <=
10.3.0.95                <=
10.3.0.96                <=
10.3.0.97                <=
10.3.0.98                <=
10.3.0.99                <=
10.3.0.100               <=
10.3.0.101               <=
10.3.0.102               <=
10.3.0.103               <=
10.3.0.104               <=
10.3.0.105               <=
10.3.0.106               <=
10.3.0.107               <=
10.3.0.108               <=
10.3.0.109               <=
10.3.0.110               <=
10.3.0.111               <=
10.3.0.112               <=
10.3.0.113               <=
10.3.0.114               <=
10.3.0.115               <=
10.3.0.116               <=
10.3.0.117               <=
10.3.0.118               <=
10.3.0.119               <=
10.3.0.120               <=
10.3.0.121               <=
10.3.0.122               <=
10.3.0.123               <=
10.3.0.124               <=
10.3.0.125               <=
10.3.0.126               <=
10.3.0.127               <=
10.3.0.128               <=
10.3.0.129               <=
10.3.0.130               <=
10.3.0.131               <=
10.3.0.132               <=
10.3.0.133               <=
10.3.0.134               <=
10.3.0.135               <=
10.3.0.136               <=
10.3.0.137               <=
10.3.0.138               <=
10.3.0.139               <=
10.3.0.140               <=
10.3.0.141               <=
10.3.0.142               <=
10.3.0.143               <=
10.3.0.144               <=
10.3.0.145               <=
10.3.0.146               <=
10.3.0.147               <=
10.3.0.148               <=
10.3.0.149               <=
10.3.0.150               <=
10.3.0.151               <=
10.3.0.152               <=
10.3.0.153               <=
10.3.0.154               <=
10.3.0.155               <=
10.3.0.156               <=
10.3.0.157               <=
10.3.0.158               <=
10.3.0.159               <=
10.3.0.160               <=
10.3.0.161               <=
10.3.0.162               <=
10.3.0.163               <=
10.3.0.164               <=
10.3.0.165               <=
10.3.0.166               <=
10.3.0.167               <=
10.3.0.168               <=
10.3.0.169               <=
10.3.0.170               <=
10.3.0.171               <=
10.3.0.172               <=
10.3.0.173               <=
10.3.0.174               <=
10.3.0.175               <=
10.3.0.176               <=
10.3.0.177               <=
10.3.0.178               <=
10.3.0.179               <=
10.3.0.180               <=
10.3.0.181               <=
10.3.0.182               <=
10.3.0.183               <=
10.3.0.184               <=
10.3.0.185               <=
10.3.0.186               <=
10.3.0.187               <=
10.3.0.188               <=
10.3.0.189               <=
10.3.0.190               <=
10.3.0.191               <=
10.3.0.192               <=
10.3.0.193               <=
10.3.0.194               <=
10.3.0.195               <=
10.3.0.196               <=
10.3.0.197               <=
10.3.0.198               <=
10.3.0.199               <=
10.3.0.200               <=
10.3.0.201               <=
10.3.0.202               <=
10.3.0.203               <=
10.3.0.204               <=
10.3.0.205               <=
10.3.0.206               <=
10.3.0.207               <=
10.3.0.208               <=
10.3.0.209               <=
10.3.0.210               <=
10.3.0.211               <=
10.3.0.212               <=
10.3.0.213               <=
10.3.0.214               <=
10.3.0.215               <=
10.3.0.216               <=
10.3.0.217               <=
10.3.0.218               <=
10.3.0.219               <=
10.3.0.220               <=
10.3.0.221               <=
10.3.0.222               <=
10.3.0.223               <=
10.3.0.224               <=
10.3.0.225               <=
10.3.0.226               <=
10.3.0.227               <=
10.3.0.228               <=
10.3.0.229               <=
10.3.0.230               <=
10.3.0.231               <=
10.3.0.232               <=
10.3.0.233               <=
10.3.0.234               <=
10.3.0.235               <=
10.3.0.236               <=
10.3.0.237               <=
10.3.0.238               <=
10.3.0.239               <=
10.3.0.240               <=
10.3.0.241               <=
10.3.0.242               <=
10.3.0.243               <=
10.3.0.244               <=
10.3.0.245               <=
10.3.0.246               <=
10.3.0.247               <=
10.3.0.248               <=
10.3.0.249               <=
10.3.0.250               <=
10.3.0.251               <=
10.3.0.252               <=
10.3.0.253               <=
10.3.0.254               <=
10.3.0.255               <=
```

Comment: Change `-DifferenceObject $result` to `-DifferenceObject $result.'IP Address'`

Comment: Thanks so much.